# Does using bit shifts really speeds up the program on modern systems?

Tags: bit-shift

I've heard that bit shift operation in modern systems are actually slower than multiplying and dividing, because they have to pass more arguments. Is that true?

Comment: You could write some code to test, but modern compilers optimize any benefits of using bitshift away.  It is pretty much generally recommended to avoid them.

Comment: What 'more arguments'? They are all binary operators. That means two arguments each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't. A C compiler will choose the fastest operations for your processor, regardless of how you specify them.

> A poster child of strength reduction is replacing x / 2 with x >> 1 in source code. In 1985, that was a good thing to do; nowadays, you're just making your compiler yawn.
>   https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/three-optimization-tips-for-c/10151361643253920